# HTML audio tag not playing songs from Amazon S3 URL

Tags: html, audio, amazon-s3, audio-player

I have an `.mp3` URL in S3 bucket and trying to play the song from my webpage using HTML `<audio>` tag. The player gets disabled and not playing the song. All my song properly getting upload to S3 bucket, and I am able to play them locally.

My code is given below:

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto" id="audio_player">< source src='https://akiaiowmyt6vxaidogxa-lw-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/lw/1502872370049.mp3' type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

S3 URL -
https://akiaiowmyt6vxaidogxa-lw-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/lw/1502872370049.mp3

How to play S3 URL MP3 songs on browser?

Answer (score 2):

The server is claiming that URL contains `application/pdf` formatted data. The browser doesn't know how to treat a PDF as audio.

You need to configure the server to send the correct content-type.

You can do this by going to the Properties section of the S3 section of the Amazon AWS Console.

Comment: Hi....thanks for the reply!! I changed the content type to audio/mpeg , still it does not work! Can you tell me the correct one too please?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<audio controls src="https://akiaiowmyt6vxaidogxa-lw-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/lw/1502872370049.mp3" preload="auto" id="audio_player" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

src must be in audio tags.
This solution work for me. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check url in any desktop player

2) space after "<" ? in "< audio" and "< /audio"

3) should be

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto" id="audio_player">
    <source src=" https://akiaiowmyt6vxaidogxa-lw-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/lw/1502872370049.mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: I have given the same code without space for audio tags .I had to give space since stackoverflow was not accepting my code without space. This is still not working!

Comment: <source> inside <audio> is missing.


Try some different source of sound to exclude syntax problem,

Comment: Check it now but only ignore the spaces before audio and source tag. Stackoverflow isn't allowing. I can save my audio only in Amazon S3 as per my project requirements.